# .NET 4.5 installed but error message when app runs

Tags: .net, runtime, app-config

I have .NET 4.5 installed on my dev machine:
[image]

However I get this message when my app runs:

[image]

I have this in my app.config:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.5" sku=".NETFramework, version=v4.5"/>
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: If you say 'yes' what happens?

Comment: My browser gets redirected to the Microsoft search page with the name of my app as a search term. Obviously it doesn't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced the `<supportedRuntime>` node with this:

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
</startup>
```

as per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) on MSDN. It works as both .NET 4 and 4.5 target the same version of the CLR, v4.0.30319.